# SiegeTest:socket error unable to connect

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, siege

Really need help to figure out what is going wrong.

Application Background: It is a `nodejs` with `socket.io` application.

I am testing my site load using `siege windows 3.0.5` tool.
70 concurrent users with 10 seconds

```
siege -c70 -t10s http://localhost:8082
```

and getting below error messages.

> [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: Address family not supported by protocol [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or   directory [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or  directory [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or  directory [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or  directory [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or  directory [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or  directory HTTP/1.1 200   8.96 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  / HTTP/1.1 200   8.96 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  / HTTP/1.1 200   8.96 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  / HTTP/1.1 200   8.96 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  / HTTP/1.1 200   8.96 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  / HTTP/1.1 200   8.98 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  / HTTP/1.1 200   8.98 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  / HTTP/1.1 200   8.98 secs:    3415 bytes ==> GET  /

it works fine, if I use

```
siege -c60 -t50s http://localhost:8082
```

Does this means I can only serve 60 concurrent users. What are above errors messages and how to resolve them.

I am already using connectionPool concept for mysql module and releasing connection after using it.

```
db.getConnection(function(err,connection)
    {
        if(!err)
        {        
            connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
                connection.release();
                if(err) {
            throw err;
                } else {
                    callback("null",{rows : rows,tablename : ticker});
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue....were you ever able to figure out what is going on.   I am using siege-windows against and IIS application.

Comment: No :-( , Mine was with socket.io... so ...I did a test using socket id display on server side....so every time socket id is different..when siege runs for more than 70+ users... and none of connection were refused. Siege somehow is not a good testing tool for nodejs or socket.io tools.

Comment: same problem as me if i use high concurrent socket, this thing will fail.. any idea how to resolve it? maybe it should use a new siege version...